# How do I update multiple columns with their respective values in laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel, performance, eloquent

I have a database record that I would like to update base on certain conditions. This condition is: when the `pay_day` is reached, I want to send the user that owns that record an email and then update the `pay_day` column to another date in the future using the `interval_day` column on the users' table. `interval_day` is just a number selected by the user.

Below is an illustration:

```
$now = Carbon::now();

User::where('approved', true)
            ->where('pay_day', '<', $now)
            ->chunkById(1000, function($users){
                foreach ($users as $user) {

                    $interval = $user->interval;
                    $payDay = $now()->addDays($interval);

                    // update the user...
                    $user->update([
                        'pay_day' => $payDay,
                    ]);
                    // if the user was updated, send an email next...
                }
                
            });
```

Now, let's say I have 100 different users with different `interval` values. I want their respective values in their `interval` columns to be what would be updated to their `pay_day` column and **NOT** the same date for all 100 users.

But when I run the above query it didn't update, neither the `pay_day` nor send email to the respective users. When I dd($interval & $payDay) it returns nothing.

Please what am I doing wrong? I need your suggestions. Thanks for your time in advance.

Comment: Is it `interval` or `interval_day`? You seem to use both in your question. Have you added `pay_day` to the `protected $fillable` array in your `User` model?

Comment: Yes. I have added the interval_day (or interval) to my fillable property.

Answer (score 2):

use like this

```
$updates = ([
                    'pay_day' => $payDay,
                  //other columns
                ]);
$x = User::where('approved', true)
        ->where('pay_day', '<', $now)->->update($updates);
if($x){
//succeed case
}
```

Comment: Ok, nice. But how do I get the values of the "pay_day" column for the respective users? From your answer, you have the update array before the main query. If you don't mind, please explain that part

Comment: i think loop is used when you are updating multiple rows, now you are updating multiple columns so hopefully it will help for you.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I got it working now. Both answers worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if `$payDay = $now()->addDays($interval);` is a typo or you've actually done that in your code, but `$now` is a variable not a function. Additionally you need to tell the closure in your `chunkById` function to `use` `$now`:

```php
\App\Models\User::where('approved', true)
    ->where('pay_day', '<', \Carbon\Carbon::today())
    ->chunkById(1000, function ($users) {
        $users->each(function ($user) {
            $success = $user->update([
                'pay_day' => \Carbon\Carbon::today()->addDays($user->interval)
            ]);
            if ($success) {
                // send email
            }
    });
});
```

The above finds all `approved` `Users` where their `pay_day` is before `today` then processes the results in chunks of `1000` and updates the `pay_day` for each of them to be `today` + the `interval` value.

Comment: When I tried this, it updated the "pay_day" of the first user for all the users. How do I make it specific to only the value each user has in their "pay_day" column? Thanks for your time though

Comment: @Leonard203 Seems to be some odd behaviour with `$now`. I have updated my answer.

Comment: It's working but only updating for the first record. I'm trying a for loop and observing what changes are made.

Comment: @Leonard203 I have editted my answer after confirming that it works. If it is not working you might have some code somewhere that is conflicting.

Comment: Yes, I see that. But it's not working on my end. Maybe I'll do a review of my code. I'll keep you posted on how it goes. Thanks for your time.

Comment: - Peppermintology I know this must have been a little long but I need your help. 
At the time, I tried the method and it seems more than 5 deposit records are due for updating all at the same time. But the method is only updating for the first record. 
Do you know a way I could get the whole collection updated with their respective payable_amount?

Comment: Thanks. It’s working well now. I was the one doing it the wrong way.